# Can add ons interact with the Compose window?

Tags: gmail-addons

Can an add-on activate when the user is composing a message? If so, can you point me to an example?

Context: I would like to detect when the user has attached a file and replace it with a link instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now there is not support for interacting with compose window.